# Electrical circuits homework

Tags: voltage, current, impedance

I am pretty new to circuits analysis and I have the following problem as homework:
[image]

ig2(t) = 4*sin(ωt + π/4),
e3(t) = 12*sin(ωt + π/4),
R1 = 10 Ω,
ωL1 = 4 Ω,
ωL3 = 3 Ω,
1/(ωC2) = 6 Ω

I have to calculate Ee and Ze with the equivalent generator method (Thevenin). I managed to calculate the impendace Ze but I don't know how to continue from there. I hope you understand the problem statement.

My attempt to solve it:
[image]

I don't think that the system is correct and I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework needs an attempt at a solution, post the attempt and reopen the question.

Comment: Please also post the question in english, which is required for posts here, thanks

Comment: @VoltageSpike I updated my question. Can you reopen it? I don't think I can reopen my question as I am new here.

Comment: Your final system of equations appears to be a mix of [nodal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_analysis) and [mesh analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_analysis). It leaves you with 3 equations and 4 unknown variables, so it's not possible to solve this. I would recommend setting up a full system of equations as a mesh analysis and then solving that system of equations to find Ee.

Comment: Since the circuits contains two sources, an easy way to compute \$E_e\$ would be to employ the superposition principle. First shorten the voltage source and compute the voltage across A and B that is caused by the current source. Second, open the current source and compute the same voltage, this time caused by the voltage source. Since the circuit is linear, you may finally add the two results.